# Batch Script: Get Files, Compare Dates and Get Filename (from latest modified date)

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

So I have the following basis for a small script I'm developing to pull all of the latest logs from several directories together. The pseudo code for this process is as follows:

- go to parent directory
- FOR every directory check whether the folder "logs" exists

  - IF "logs" is present go to that directory
  - VAR fname VAR fdate (the most up to date file)
  - FOR every file F in "logs"

    - IF fname is empty fname=F fdate=Fd
    - ELSE IF Fd > fdate fname=F fdate=Fd
  - END FOR
- Copy log file (fname) to "all logs"
- END FOR

Below is an extract of the batch code I've got so far which covers the main process of comparing the file dates:

```
FOR /d %%d in (*) DO (
  CD %%d

  IF /I EXIST logs (
    CD logs

    SET fname
    SET fdate

    FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b !CD!\!d!') DO (
      IF [%fname%]==[] (
        %fname%=%%f
        %fdate%=%%~tf
      ) ELSE (
        REM Compare modified dates to determine which is the latest file. 
        IF %%~tf GTR %fdate% (
          %fdate%=%%~tf
          %fname%=%%f
        )
      )
    REM Copy the log file ...
    REM ... 
    )
  CD %pdir%
)

:END 
CD %wdir%
```

I think I'm off to a running start, but it isn't perfect and the troubles I'm having are that the files are actually opening when %%~tf is called; and the structure of storing and comparing the dates is off (I'm thinking as a programmer and not as a scripter!). Could someone please advise on these issues and offer any feedback, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be greatly simplified. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /d %%a in (*) do (
  if /i exist !cd!\%%a\logs (
    Call :getlatestfile "!cd!\%%a\logs" latest
    echo copy "%%a\logs\!latest!" "C:\path\to\copy\to"
  )
)
exit /b

:getlatestfile <path> <return>
setlocal
for /f %%b in ('dir "%~1" /b /o-d /tw') do set "latest=%%b" & goto :out
:out
endlocal & set "%~2=%latest%"
```

remove the echo from the copy line once you see acceptable results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was indeed greatly simplified and helped further my understanding of methods within batch scripting further. Thank you again for the help.

... You might have also noticed I updated the code - as the "copy" command is not pointing at the correct location of the file.

Comment: May I ask a final question...? As I'd now like to merge all files together, how would I go about achieving this? So far I've tried altering the copy to point to a file rather than directory, but this just updates the file with the last log file found, instead of appending them.

Comment: if all of the files have the same extension you can do something like `copy log*.txt newlogfile.txt`

Comment: Extending the code above (of the original question) I just changed it to:
 copy "%%a\logs\!latest!" %wdir%\logs.txt

This just adds the last found file to the logs.txt file. If I added "*.txt" to the left side of the copy then wouldn't that append it? For instance making "..\a_log.txt" to "..\a_log.txt*.txt"?